# Check if a value exists in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is there a way to check if a value exists in a mysql column? I have table songs, and there are some columns, one of them is called 'agent_ip' where i will put a list/array of all user ip's that will visit the site. I need to check if current user ip is present in column 'agent_ip'. Here is some of my code:

```
public function voteSong($song_id, $case, $agent_ip) {           
    $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"); 
    $query->bindValue(1, $song_id);
    $query->execute();
    $rowcount = $query->rowCount();        

    if ($rowcount != 0)
    {
        if (!in_array($agent_ip, $r['ip']))
        {
            if ($case === 'like')
            {
                while($r = $query->fetch())
                {
                    $vote = $r['votes'] + 1;
                }
            } 
            elseif ($case === 'dislike')
            {
                while ($r = $query->fetch())
                { 
                    if ($r['votes'] > 0)
                    {
                        $vote = $r['votes'] - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $vote = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE songs SET datetime = ?, votes = ?, agent_ip = ? WHERE id = ?"); 
            $query->execute(array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $vote, $agent_ip, $song_id));
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if(!in_array($agent_ip, $r['ip']))` contains the wrong function which won't work, but i need an alternative for mysql. $r['ip'] variable is data from the 'agent_ip' column which look like this 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1 (using 127.0.0.1 just for example, every 127.0.0.1 is a different ip)

Comment: First off, please post your code as *text*, not a picture.  Second... take another look at that line.  What is `$r`?  Where do you declare it?

Comment: `$r` isn't defined there.

Comment: No text; no help. No one will steal your *precious* code.

Comment: Definitely need to know what this mystery $r variable is...

Comment: What code editor you were using? Is it Notepad++?

Comment: well, it's my mistake, didn't notice it before putting it here, i had something like while($r = $query->fetch){ and here goes all the code between if($rowcount != 0) }

Comment: @bad_boy i am using brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only checking against a single IP, why don't you just modify your query from:

```
"SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"
```

To:

```
"SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = ? AND agent_ip = ? LIMIT 1"
```

It seems a bit wasteful to query your whole result set when you are only querying against a specific IP and returning a single row.

EDIT: Your current method would be extremely inefficient, you are passing a unique `agent_ip` each time you want to query a song to check if the IP exists, that would be fine, but you are creating a new DB connection every time from which you pull back all info which belongs to that song.

Lets say we have 1 song, and 3IP's, currently the application would work like this:

```
1) Call the method, passing IP_1
2) Query the database getting all songs for ID1
3) Check if IP_1 is in the result set and do process

4) Call the method, passing IP_2
5) Query the database getting all songs for ID1
6) Check if IP_2 is in the result set and do process

7) Call the method, passing IP_3
8) Query the database getting all songs for ID1
9) Check if IP_2 is in the result set and do process
```

As you can see, there is a lot of repetition here which is going to hinder your apps performance as it scales, you would be so much better modifying your current function to accept a list of results for a song which is pre-queried only once and then recursively call a check function by passing that result array with your unique IP address.

**UPDATE** You stated  `I understand that i need to have 2 tables(1 = songs; 2 = votes). But i cannot imagine how i will get songs from database, arranged by votes quantity.`

You should read SQL's `JOIN` documentation, the concept is simple - JOIN allows you to pull back a more detailed set of information based on what you want to query, in your example you may want to find out how many votes a specific song has.

Your tables may look like:

```
Songs 
SONG_ID     Primary Key
SONG_TITLE  
SONG_DURATION
SONG_TAGS

Votes
VOTE_ID     Primary Key
SONG_ID     Foreign Key - (references the song_id table)
VOTE_RES    Bool (either 0 for no, 1 for yes)
AGENT_IP    Who sent the vote
```

You could then find out how many people said they liked the song by performing a join:

```
SELECT * FROM songs 
JOIN votes 
ON songs.song_id = votes.song_id 
WHERE songs.song_id = 1 
AND votes.vote_res = 1;
```

This would return all the song with the id of 1 and all of its associated likes.  Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: I need to check every single ip that will access site.

Comment: I see, if that is the case why does your method signature accept the `agent_ip` parameter, as that would be unique and therefore redundant for how you are currently querying your system.

Comment: If i got you right, then the answer is: my method accept the `agent_ip` parameter because i have outside a function which takes the user ip, so i can check if this ip exists also in my 'array' in mysql column.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not pointing how to fix your problem - but I am trying to save you some problems from an architecture perspective :)

Comment: We all start somewhere :)

Comment: Then can i get some ideas on how to make my project better? The idea is that i need to make a list of songs, then i have to let user vote a song once(+ or -). That's it. I understand that i need to have 2 tables(1 = songs; 2 = votes). But i cannot imagine how i will get songs from database, arranged by votes quantity.

Comment: Check my update - in terms of quantity you should look at SQL's `COUNT` and `GROUP` methods

Comment: I will definitely try this code, it looks very promising to me :3 But how do i arrange the list of songs i got like in a top or something like that. The song with the most votes is positioned 1st, and the song with lowest quantity of votes goes last?

Comment: So you want to say find out the current top most voted songs and arrange them in order?  For that you would need to combine SQL's `JOIN`, `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` methods and then also use a `subquery` to recrusively find the total amount of upvotes for a song - you could then use `ORDER BY count(votes) DESC` to put them in order, I can't answer the SQL questions here as it is really out of scope of the initial question - you should open up a new thread when you have tried some of this stuff yourself...it would be great to do some further reading on what I have just discussed...good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you helped me a lot. Definitely have to read some more SQL documentation.

Comment: Just want to share the code i'm using now: `SELECT * FROM songs LEFT JOIN votes ON songs.id = votes.song_id AND votes.vote_res = 1 GROUP BY songs.id ORDER BY (COUNT(votes.id)) DESC` Hope it does not contain any mistakes, also, thanks again to @Alex

Comment: You're welcome.   Looks good to me as long as it's bringing you back the expected results you're golden. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to deserialize/decode the data from the column to the proper php `array` and then you can use `in_array` function. In your post edit you stated that you have a comma separated list of IP's, so to convert it to array you need to use an `explode` function:

```
$ip_list = explode(', ', $r['ip']);
```

now you can use the `in_array` function on the new array:

```
if(!in_array($agent_ip, $ip_list))
```

Comment: That must be because your column in the table is named `agent_ip` and you're trying to get the 'ip' column from your result set. Try changing the `$r['ip']` to `$r['agent_ip']`. And as Alex pointed out you should really rethink your architecture design.

Comment: Unfortunately, i changed that a while ago, after i posted code here, it's not working :(

Comment: Then there must be some other problems that are not directly related to your question. TBH I would drop the code you're writing right now and take Alex's advice to learn some more about SQL. Happy coding! :)